# Disable an event for all widgets of a specific type in TCL/TK

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I would like to disable an event for a specific type of widget in TCL/TK. Specifically, I don't want the mousewheel to change the selected item in a ttk::combobox. I found `bind .widget <<event>> break` can be used to unbind. I was able to successfully unbind a `ttk::combobox` using the following lines.

```
bind .cb <MouseWheel> break
bind .cb <4> break
bind .cb <5> break
```

I would like to do this for all `ttk::combobox`'s. I found it is possible with tkinter from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44268882/remove-ttk-combobox-mousewheel-binding) answer, so I am inclined to believe its possible with TCL/TK.

I have tried the following to no avail.

```
bind ttk::combobox <MouseWheel> break
bind ttk::combobox <4> break
bind ttk::combobox <5> break
```

I used the `bind widget_type <event> procedure` format from the [manual](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/bind.html) which contains the lines below.

```
bind Entry <<Paste>> {puts Paste}
bind Entry <<Scroll>> {puts Scroll}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem to be `ttk::combobox` is not the class name. Changing `ttk::combobox` to `TCombobox` fixed the problem.

```
bind TCombobox <MouseWheel> break
bind TCombobox <4> break
bind TCombobox <5> break
```

Comment: For arcane reasons relating to how resource names work, widget class names can't (easily) contain colons and must start with a capital letter. It's *very* ugly. If you only need to turn things off for a subset of comboboxes, use the `bindtags` command to give those widgets an extra binding tag (with the right priority) and put your bindings on that.